# Comments being deleted mysteriously

Tags: discussion, comment, deletion

I don't know why my comments I placed on a question made by an asker are being deleted. I would like to hear an explanation. I think I should be informed first that my comment probably does not like the boss, so I can change it or delete. It is really annoying to just delete it without informing.

Answer (score 12):

There are three ways that comments can be deleted.

1. The commenter can delete it himself.
2. If 3 people flag the comment, it automatically gets deleted (with a cost of an additional 3 people per comment upvote).
3. If a moderator deletes it.

Many of Don Anselmo's comments have been deleted, some through all three. Instead of demanding attention, I encourage the OP to decide what parts of his behavior have been deemed inappropriate by the community.

For information about comments, I encourage you to read the faq [section on it](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). I'd like to emphasize that comments should not by nature contain significant information. Instead, they are for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or for giving minor or transient information. MSE (as do many of the other SEs) has its own less-prescribed, more subtle and nuanced take on comments - you can learn about these as you experience the site more.